# I am bit confused about number of stalls in MIPS pipelined processor

Tags: cpu-architecture

I recently read in book by H Patterson that number of stalls(without forwarding)
in a MIPS pipelined processor would be 3 between two add instruction as below:
add s0,s1,s2
add s4,s3,s0
But my instructor told that it would be 2 as the first add instruction will write in the register in first half of the cycle of WRITEBACK stage and hence it will be availaible for INSTRUCTION DECODE stage for next instruction in second half of the cycle.Which one of this is correct with MIPS processor?

Answer (score -1):

Well i got it right away!! It can be both of them...refer to this..
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse410/05sp/lectures/cse410-10-pipelining-a.pdf